# Windows command line execute pdftk.exe with arguments length > 8192 characters

Tags: command-line, windows-console, pdftk

I need to merge ~1000 pdf files. I call pdftk from my program for this purpose. However, it happens that input arguments exceeds maximum Windows command line character length of 8192 and i get error.

I tried to store my input in txt file, but without success:

> pdftk < file.txt
>
> type file.txt  | pdftk

It looks like, that pdftk does not get input from redirection, pipe operators.

I tested it on Windows 10.

Does anyone know how it can be achieved?

Comment: You can get more if you set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false.  Redirection can only work if you use cmd.exe /c to execute the program.

Comment: The command line of a Windows process can have up to 32766 characters, but cmd.exe is limited to 8192 characters.

Comment: Ok I got. It turns out, that I reached the limit of 32766 characters. However, this limit is sufficient for my needs. I only have to change the names of files to shorter one. By the way, is the limit of 32766 the absolute one, or it can be extended somehow?