# Way around max command-line length?

Tags: windows, command-line, pdftk

I am using pdftk to merge two PDFs but they are so large that the parameters are causing the command to exceed the maximum character length. Is there any way around this?

Something I haven't tried: 
Store chunks of the command in a variable, concatenating them together and then using that variable in the final command

Workaround I have tried:
When my parameters hit a certain length, cut off that command, complete it, and then start over where I left off with new parameters. This works, but effectively multiplies my run-time depending on how many times I'll need to execute the command.

Comment: [This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46727043/62576), specifically about PDFTk. While that question wasn't answered, the comments to it might be helpful. See also [Command prompt command-line string limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation)  Short answer: No, unless PDFTk will accept its parameter inputs from a file, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a partial solution using the powershell command "Start-Process":

```
$pdftk = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe"
$params = "A=`"C:\PDF\a.pdf`" B=`"C:\PDF\b.pdf`" cat A1 B1 output `"C:\PDF\out.pdf`""
start-process $pdftk $params -wait
```

This will give you a new max of 32766 characters, which is much easier to work with. Be sure to use full paths and escape your quotes to get everything working right, as this method does not pass existing variables through to this new "process".